# How do progressive load article in javascript

Tags: javascript, load, progressive

How do progressive load cells flock together after the end of the page in javascript ?

[This is my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqvRQ.png)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

It's called [Infinite scroll](https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/).

You can find a lot of tutorial and demos with this keyword.

Comment: For example, please?

Comment: You have one link in the answer

Comment: Sorry i am blind :D